# reading a text file

Tags: c#, xaml, file-io

I'm trying to read a txt file in the event handler

```
private void abc (object sender, routedEventArgs e)
{
     string [] x= File.ReadAllLinwes(path);
}
```

i get the error :
The name FILE does not exist in the current content

So, how do you read from a text file in xaml.cs file?
what should be imported?

Comment: are you sure that path is valid and there's a file there?

Comment: Did you lookup the `System.IO` namespace?

Comment: @kenny The error message looks like a compile time error, not an exception.

Answer (score 3):

[The `File` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.aspx) is in the `System.IO` namespace. So adding `using System.IO;` to the top of your C# file will most likely fix the issue.